# Footer goes up whenever i open Chrome Console

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

So, I admit I'm not that good at CSS, and this might be something dumb on my end, but I want to have a sticky footer at the bottom of every page on my site.

I'm using a position absolute this is the CSS for my footer

```
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:50px;
    padding: 10px;
    width:100%;
```

It works when the console is closed, but if I open the Chrome Developer tools, the footer suddenly goes up as if it were fixed to the browser window which is not the case.

Am I doing anything wrong?

How do others do sticky footers?

EDIT

I've created a simple codepen with an example of the issue

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMLBdJ

Open the dev tools below the footer and you'll notice the footer is still visible, shouldn't it be invisible behind the dev tools? That's the questions. sorry ahead of time if it's a dumb one.

Comment: We need to see the rest of your code. Give us a [mcve] that shows the current behavior.

Comment: @MichaelCoker i've updated the question with a very simple Codepen, just open the dev tools and you'll notice the footer is still visible when it shouldn't be. That's the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the height of your footer you could try:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

// wrapper around all content
main {
    min-height: 100%;
}

main::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 70px; // height + padding
}

footer {
    background: grey;
    margin-top: -70px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

With this the footer is at the bottom unless the content exceeds the window height. If you want the footer to be fixed to window just add:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/MusikAnimal/pen/OpLeEM

Answer (score 2):

In case of `position: absolute` The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

If you want to make it stick to the window, use `position:fixed`

You can play around with it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position)

And for your sticky footer, you should refer to this nice [article](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)